Create query statement from a resultset of a previous query
This is the original table: "multiactualusetest"



TAXDECNUM
ACTUALUSE
TAXABLE
MARKETVALUE
ASSESSEDVALUE




G-508659
S
Y
182000
0


G-508659
C
Y
166600
16660


G-508659
A
Y
9768
3910


G-508659
R
Y
140000
9800


G-432185
R
Y
65000
4550


G-432185
A
Y
9041.09
3620


E-008926
A
Y
20346.12
940


E-008926
A
Y
7360
540


E-008926
R
Y
27000
5500


G-508847
R
Y
21500
1510



From the multiactualusetest table above, the following table was created using this query:
SELECT TAXDECNUM, 
       ACTUALUSE, 
       TAXABLE, 
       SUM(MARKETVALUE) AS TOTAL_MARKETVALUE, 
       SUM(ASSESSEDVALUE) AS TOTAL_ASSESSEDVALUE 
FROM multiactualusetest 
GROUP BY TAXDECNUM, ACTUALUSE 
ORDER BY TAXDECNUM, ACTUALUSE

What it did was to sum up the MARKETVALUE and ASSESSEDVALUE of all similar ACTUALUSE from each TAXDECNUM. In the multiactualusetest table, only TAXDECNUM rows containing E-008926 has 2 similar ACTUALUSE rows of "A". So, the following resulting resultset shows it.



TAXDECNUM
ACTUALUSE
TAXABLE
TOTAL_MARKETVALUE
TOTAL_ASSESSEDVALUE




E-008926
A
Y
27706.12
1480


E-008926
R
Y
27000
5500


G-432185
A
Y
9041.09
3620


G-432185
R
Y
65000
4550


G-508659
A
Y
9768
3910


G-508659
C
Y
166600
16660


G-508659
R
Y
140000
9800


G-508659
S
Y
182000
0


G-508847
R
Y
21500
1510



Now, I want another result set that will show the following columns:
TAXDECNUM, ACTUALUSE, COUNTX, TAXABLE, MARKETVALUE, ASSESSEDVALUE

where the COUNTX is 1 when the TOTAL_MARKETVALUE is maximum for each TAXDECNUM. All the other COUNTX for the  non-maximum TOTAL_MARKETVALUE values are 0.
The result should be as follows:



TAXDECNUM
ACTUALUSE
COUNTX
TAXABLE
MARKETVALUE
ASSESSEDVALUE




E-008926
A
1
Y
27706.12
1480


E-008926
R
0
Y
27000
5500


G-432185
A
0
Y
9041.09
3620


G-432185
R
1
Y
65000
4550


G-508659
A
0
Y
9768
3910


G-508659
C
0
Y
166600
16660


G-508659
R
0
Y
140000
9800


G-508659
S
1
Y
182000
0


G-508847
R
1
Y
21500
1510



Note: Such keywords as CTE, OVER, PARTITION ...it doesn't work as I'm using PHPMYADMIN MySQL. So, I think these should probably consists of queries on subqueries.
Please help.
The AI sites I sought help generated query statements that involved creating temporary tables like the following:
SELECT TAXDECNUM, 
       ACTUALUSE, 
       TAXABLE, 
       SUM(MARKETVALUE) AS TOTAL_MARKETVALUE, 
       SUM(ASSESSEDVALUE) AS TOTAL_ASSESSEDVALUE 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM `multiactualusetest` 
GROUP BY TAXDECNUM, ACTUALUSE

SELECT TAXDECNUM, 
       ACTUALUSE, 
       CASE WHEN TOTAL_MARKETVALUE = (SELECT MAX(TOTAL_MARKETVALUE) 
                                      FROM #TempTable AS t2 
                                      WHERE t2.TAXDECNUM = t1.TAXDECNUM) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS COUNTX, 
       TAXABLE, 
       TOTAL_MARKETVALUE, 
       TOTAL_ASSESSEDVALUE
FROM #TempTable AS t1
ORDER BY TAXDECNUM, ACTUALUSE

DROP TABLE #TempTable

This did not work either as PhpMyAdmin doesn't seem to like multiple separate query statements lumped into one.

As far as I’m aware, PHPMYADMIN will run any valid SQL command and mySQL supports CTEs - so why do you think CTEs aren’t supported? Which version of mySQL are you using?

@NickW, I’ll check it as soon as i get back to the office. Probably old version because CTE’s aren’t recognized. Thanks for the heads up though. Perhaps i’ll just ask our admin to update.

@NickW, oh my, can you believe it? It's version 5.6.20!
